# What do the limits represent on a Riemann–Stieltjes integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, stieltjes-integral

Say I have the integral

$$
\int_0^{10} 1\ d(x^2)
$$

Are the limits on the range of $x$ or of $x^2$ ?

Based on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) I am assuming it is the limits of $x$ in which case I imagine the answer here is:

$$
\int_0^{10} 1\ d(x^2) = \int_0^{10} 2x\ dx = [x^2]^{10}_0 = 100
$$

Or alternatively is it a limit on $x^2$ ? e.g.  using $z = x^2$

$$
\int_0^{10} 1\ d(x^2) = \int_0^{10} 1\ dz = [z]^{10}_0 = 10
$$

Any help / clarification would be appreciated !

Comment: The limit is not on $x^2\,.$ If you find a reference that claims that please let me know.

Comment: The limits are on $x$, else it would make an intractable integral definition. Here with limits on $x^2$ negative bounds would be forbidden, and this would be nearly impossible to get something useful with oscillating $g(x)$. Imagine also for instance if a bound is on $g(x)=0$ then you do not even know how to deal with that for $g$ polynomial of degree 5+.